# How do I access nested arrays within laravel views? Laravel 4

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-4

I am unable to access the internal values of the following array.

for Object 1 to access the ***VALUES IN THE FIRST OBJECT I USED *** values I used the following method:

```
{{$info[0]->title}} 
{{$info[0]->about}}
```

I am trying to access the **VALUES IN THE INTERNAL ARRAYS**... How can I?

```
 [

{*"pageID":1,"userID":2,"title":"CrossFit Invictus","logo":"","about":"Invictus is a 5,000 sq\/ft. fitness coaching facility equipped with men\u2019s and women\u2019s locker rooms and a designated kid\u2019s area, located in Little Italy\/Downtown San Diego, California. We offer group, semi-private and individual coaching. Our workouts are comprised of constantly varied functional movements (like pushing, pulling, squatting, lifting, running) in a manner designed to help you achieve your fitness goals.","links":"Street\r\nCar park","createdDate":"2013-10-28 14:14:40","status":1*},


    [

    {"postID":1,"author":1,"pageID":1,"type":"2","post_date":"2013-10-28 00:00:00","visibility":0,"content":"**Now I been datin this girl named Katie, she hot as hell\r\nAnd her body crazy, body shaven and it dont smell\r\nAnd I don't fall for chickens\r\nBut this one a little different\r\nBody sickening\r\nPlus she really good at making breaded chicken**","image":"EHJTRHTJ","youtube_url":"FFEFEFEWFED","is_profile":0,"likes":0,"comments":0,"post_status":1},
    {"postID":2,"author":5,"pageID":1,"type":"1","post_date":"2013-10-27 10:21:15","visibility":0,"content":"posts about empires","image":"dfsfsf","youtube_url":"efefefef","is_profile":0,"likes":0,"comments":0,"post_status":1},{"postID":6,"author":12,"pageID":1,"type":"1","post_date":"2013-10-27 00:00:00","visibility":0,"content":"post about emperors ","image":"fhfghfh","youtube_url":"hththt","is_profile":1,"likes":0,"comments":0,"post_status":1}

      ],

      [
    {"id":1,"person":1,"page":1,"reason":"blab blab blab blab blabber","positive":1, "time_posted": "**2013-10-28 15:14:43**"}
      ]


    ]
```

Query I used to pass data to view:

```
//Retrieve  BASIC PAGE INFO
        $page       = DB::table('pages')->where('pageID', $id)->first();
        $page_posts =  DB::table('pagesposts')->where('pageID', $id)->get();
        $page_likes =  DB::table('pagelikes')->where('page', $id)->get();

  //Page data 
        $info = array ($page, $page_posts, $page_likes) ;



        return View::make('testingview', compact('info'));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass your data like this:

```
//Page data 
        $info = array();
        $info['page'] = $page;
        $info['page_posts'] = $page_posts;
        $info['page_likes'] = $page_likes; 

return View::make('testingview', $info);
```

and then in your view you can access it like separate variables:

```
$page, $page_posts and $page_likes
```

for example:

```
{{ $page->title }}
```

You should note that invoking the [compact()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php) function creates an array containing variables and their value and this is most likely the root of your issue.

Comment: Great fix. Worked well thank you "glad to help". I was using compact out of habit without regard for the purpose.

Comment: @kriskaman Please mark it as Correct answer with a green checkmark