# Laravel nested navigation

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I am working on creating a nested navigation for categories and subcategories. I have a construct function in the `BaseController` that shares a variable to the views which returns everything from a Category Model.

**Base Controller**

```
public function __construct() {
        $this->beforeFilter(function() {
                View::share('catnav', Category::all());
        });
}
```

So far, I can display the category's name and an array of objects for the subcategories like so:

```
@foreach($catnav as $cat)
<li>{{ HTML::link('/store/category/'.$cat->id, $cat->name) }}
    <ul>
       <li>{{ HTML::link('/store/category/'.$cat->id, $cat->subcategories) }}</li>
    </ul>
</li>
@endforeach
```

The above has an output of:

```
- Category Name
   - [{"id":6,"category_id":2,"name":"Electric","created_at":"2014-11-14 15:13:23","updated_at":"2014-11-14 15:13:23"},{"id":7,"category_id":2,"name":"Acoustic","created_at":"2014-11-14 15:13:26","updated_at":"2014-11-14 15:13:26"}]
- Another Category Name
```

The questions:

- How can I access the nested array's name property?
- Is this going to work for creating subcategories navigation?

I've already looked at [Access nested array within laravel views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19665998/how-do-i-access-nested-arrays-within-laravel-views-laravel-4), [Nested sets laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20970272/laravel-4-eager-loading-and-categories-subcategories-articles) and [Sub-categories display under Main categories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24257892/laravel-sub-categories-display-under-main-categories)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If its a limited number of levels you can just add another `foreach` loop

```
@foreach($catnav as $cat)
    <li>{{ HTML::link('/store/category/'.$cat->id, $cat->name) }}
        <ul>
            @foreach($cat->subcategories as $subcat)
                <li>{{ HTML::link('/store/category/'.$cat->id.'/sub/'.$subcat->id, $subcat->name) }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </li>
@endforeach
```

For the actual URL I just made guess, but I'm sure you can adjust that to your needs by yourself.
Also note that you might want to have an if first that checks if it even has subcategories. Just let me know if you need any help with that.

Comment: A million thanks lukas, up voted and accepted the answer! I haven't tried to add a second foreach loop and this did the trick!